# TalkBack reads layouts via an include in an unexpected order (when swiping)

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

When swiping, there seems to be a TalkBack speaking order issue with layouts added via an include.

I have the following layout (note the last include element):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faqTitle"
        style="@style/pearsonHeadingStyleWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/frequently_asked_question"
        android:text="@string/faq"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/faqWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faqTitle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/faqDetailTwoButtonPanel"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/include_two_button_bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/faqDetailTwoButtonPanel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the XML for the include:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomTwoButtonPanel"
    style="@style/pearsonBottomButtonPanelStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/frag_faq_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomTwoButtonPanelTitleText"
        style="@style/pearsonBottomButtonPanelTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/faq_feedback_msg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/faq_feedback_msg_accessability"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottomTwoButtonPanelTitleText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomTwoButtonPanelNegativeButton"
            style="@style/onBoardingTwoButtonStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/pss_gutter_padding"
            android:text="@string/no"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomTwoButtonPanelPositiveButton"
            style="@style/onBoardingTwoButtonStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/pss_gutter_padding"
            android:text="@string/yes" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 5/10/2016** - View Hierarchy dump below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
    <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1440,2392]">
        <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1440,2392]">
            <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1440,2392]">
                <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,88][1440,2392]">
                    <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/decor_content_parent" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,88][1440,2392]">
                        <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/action_bar_container" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,88][1440,284]">
                            <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/action_bar" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,88][1440,284]">
                                <node index="0" text="PowerSchool" resource-id="" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[56,139][472,232]" />
                            </node>
                        </node>
                        <node index="1" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,284][1440,2392]">
                            <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,284][1440,2392]">
                                <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/onBoardingFragmentPlaceholder" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,284][1440,2392]">
                                    <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,284][1440,2392]">
                                        <node index="0" text="FAQ" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/faqTitle" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="Frequently Asked Question" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,284][1440,457]" />
                                        <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.webkit.WebView" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,457][1440,2078]">
                                            <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.webkit.WebView" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,457][1440,2078]">
                                                <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="Why am I not receiving push notifications on the PowerSchool Mobile app?" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,502][1396,649]" />
                                                <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,712][1396,1668]">
                                                    <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="Your school's PowerSchool server must be on PowerSchool 9.1 (Mobile API 2.2.1) or greater." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,712][1344,859]" />
                                                    <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="&#10;" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,457][0,457]" />
                                                    <node index="2" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="&#10;" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,457][0,457]" />
                                                    <node index="3" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="Note" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,933][182,1006]" />
                                                    <node index="4" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc=": An issue was discovered in PowerSchool (v9.0 - v9.0.2, API version 2.2.0) that would push incorrect grades and attendance notifications to mobile devices in some circumstances. This issue is now resolved and is included in PowerSchool 9.1." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,933][1393,1374]" />
                                                    <node index="5" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="&#10;" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,457][0,457]" />
                                                    <node index="6" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="&#10;" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,457][0,457]" />
                                                    <node index="7" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="For additional help, see " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,1447][707,1521]" />
                                                    <node index="8" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="How do I find what mobile API version my school's PowerSchool server is running?" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[45,1447][1319,1668]" />
                                                    <node index="9" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc=" FAQ." checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[549,1594][707,1668]" />
                                                </node>
                                            </node>
                                        </node>
                                        <node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/faqDetailTwoButtonPanel" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,2078][1440,2392]">
                                            <node index="0" text="Did this FAQ answer your question?" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/bottomTwoButtonPanelTitleText" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="Did this F.A.Q. answer your question?" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[18,2096][1422,2198]" />
                                            <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[18,2198][1422,2374]">
                                                <node index="0" text="No" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/bottomTwoButtonPanelNegativeButton" class="android.widget.Button" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[36,2216][702,2356]" />
                                                <node index="1" text="Yes" resource-id="com.powerschool.portal:id/bottomTwoButtonPanelPositiveButton" class="android.widget.Button" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[738,2216][1404,2356]" />
                                            </node>
                                        </node>
                                    </node>
                                </node>
                            </node>
                        </node>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1440,88]" />
        </node>
        <node index="1" text="" resource-id="android:id/statusBarBackground" class="android.view.View" package="com.powerschool.portal" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1440,88]" />
    </node>
</hierarchy>
```

**Update 5/10/2016** - OS, Device and TalkBack version:

- Device: Nexus 6
- OS: Lollipop / 5.1.1
- Talkback 4.5.0.1

With TalkBack 4.5.0.1 enabled, when the screen loads, as I swipe through each view, the spoken order is: *screen title and each action bar element* > **faqTitle** > **faqWebView**.

**bottomTwoButtonPanel** (layout added via the include) is skipped. The only way to get to it is by navigating to the screen title, then swiping in the opposite direction.

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. Is there any way to control the next spoken text after **faqWebView** so that the elements in **bottomTwoButtonPanel** are spoken next?
3. Is this something that should even be worried about - i.e., should I just rely on users with sight impairments using the [Explore by Touch](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006598?hl=en) feature to figure out where to "go" on the screen?

I've tried setting `android:focusable="true"` in the included relative layout, but that had no effect on the spoken order. Additionally, I understand that [Focus Handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FocusHandling) does not apply in this case.

Comment: Can you post the view heirarchy UI Dump?  Also, can you please share which Android Device and OS Version you're using. These are more important in this case than TalkBack Version.  Yes, you should be worried about it.  That spoken order matches visual order is very important.

Comment: Added the requested info, @ChrisCM. Thanks.

Comment: Note the same behavior is observed on a Nexus 9 running Android OS 6.0.1 and TalkBack 4.5.0.

Comment: After doing some more work/investigation on this, it appears that the issue is actually the inability of TalkBack to navigate / speak the content after the WebView (**faqWebView**). I first tried directly adding the layout contained in the include in the parent RelativeLayout, but that made no difference. I then removed **faqWebView** and TalkBack spoke the content of **bottomTwoButtonPanel** right after the title (the expected order). I also tried to replacing the WebView with a TextView (same attributes as on the WebView) and there was no navigation / spoken order issue in this case, either.